# jQuery questions ruining SO

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderators

They are. Not only is SO overrun with *beginner* jQuery questions, there seem to be these "rep vultures" that just hang around waiting to answer these dumb, lazy questions with slightly less dumb but equally as lazy answers.

It's saturating SO. The majority of these questions should be closed but aren't because of these rep-hungry simpletons who probably keep them open for their own gain.

So what now? Time for a reboot? Ban jQuery from SO? Get the mods to focus on these questions properly?

It's ruining SO.

[Read this](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow)

Comment: First it was PHP, then it was Android, now it's jQuery...

Comment: @devnull Yeah, I swear Python questions are either very intellectual and iteresting or 'really?' add a colon on line 5'.

Comment: The mods have nothing to do with this. Your community does. use the tools at your disposal and start cleaning up the mess. No mods needed

Comment: @Bart You seem to remind me of Shog9.  (I'm not arguing that the community cannot handle it.  This mess is due to the community.)

Comment: Add [tag:jquery] to your ignored tags. Problem solved.

Comment: @Makoto don't forget Regex

Comment: I am currently compiling an answer @LiverpoolsNumber9. There is nothing patronising about my comment. Maybe you're the example user and you run through your daily close and downvotes. Wonderful. But I bet you that your general concerned community doesn't. So you (the community, not you personally) should perhaps assemble and get to work. Filter close vote queues by jquery only. Assemble in chat and point out really bad content for evaluation. You have plenty of tools at your disposal and I would be surprised to hear that you are using them to their full potential already.

Comment: @Bart Fair enough mate. But listen, I don't think it's a community issue. It's an issue with the way the site is set up to run. It's the *volume* of basic jQuery questions that needs to be dealt with. At the moment I could spend a day or two on here answering those questions and increase my rep massively, probably with mostly crap answers. That's not good, and no (feasibly likely) amount of community action will help that.

Comment: We have a grand total of 17 mods for the site. The ENTIRE site. Not just jQuery. And only a subset of them will know enough about jQuery to say anything about question quality/suitability if it's not the most obvious crap. You as a community are far larger, far more knowledgeable, and far more focused. Yes this requires a community effort. No, this is not a matter of mod involvement, tag banning or anything like that.

Comment: `I've scored over 14,000 points in their gaming system` It really says something about a user when they don't even know the basic site terminology.

Comment: You're saying it's saturating SO (I agree very much), but then refer to "[read this](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow)". For me, saturation yielding people stopping participating is not the problem, *if* SE would still be the one-stop great resource for the programming problems I'm facing. However, I feel it's getting harder to *find* my answers on SO. (Or even the questions.) And yes, I very much agree that's due to crap questions that are kept alive with crap answers. Too much noise.

Comment: You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: +1, Glad I'm not the only one! I hate jQuery! People using it are mostly novices and aren't building meaningful applications. For best perf, there's no substitute for plain JS in the browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hello, my name is Shadow Wizard, and I am a rep vulture.

I am not proud of this.

I am sometimes ashamed of this.

My excuse is "if you can't beat them, join them".

Stack Overflow is flooded with crap aka low quality questions, this is a fact that already discussed in the highest voted question here on MSO. The [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) crap is just a branch, same color.

I know that ideally, I should be fighting the tide, downvote, vote  to close, put comments, explain, edit. But it's a lost cause, pointless, like trying to empty the ocean with a bucket. With all due self respect, I'm not that guy:

[image]

So it's either leave it all alone and find something else to  do with my time, or do my best to somehow give something useful to the programmers world.

So yes, when I spot a no-total-crap question with some merit and with something I know, I post an answer and usually try to make it generic, so it's useful not only to the OP of the question. Or at least explain beyond "here is the code, use it".

Ideal? No. End of Stack Overflow? Maybe, but I'm not in position to change it.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 to clear any doubts, I'm not in favor of banning jQuery in Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know. Neither am I. I want to see jQuery questions, but not all the crap ones, and I don't want to see people gaining rep from answering them (mostly badly).

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 oh, you want to eat the cake and leave it whole. Or turn lead to gold. Or find source of endless energy. All are equally impossible! :(

Comment: @Sha, you're too harsh with yourself. As you say, you usually provide explanations for the code in your answers, fiddles to test it, etc. That's an order of magnitude better than "Try this:" followed by a bunch a cabalistic incantations, sometimes differing from the code in the question by only one character.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks, but many times I feel like the question is too easy and I just repeat the obvious.

Comment: No, I disagree. Closing/Downvoting/Whatever > Not doing anything > Answering crap questions. That's because when you answer crap, crap gets encouraged more and more. If we as a community not stop it, no one will.

Answer (score 9):

Although I agree with the sentiment, I disagree with banning the tag. There is always the chance that a good question will come up.

If you see a "dumb" question you should downvote it. Similarly, if you see a bad answer, downvote.

If somebody receives enough negative votes, they get blocked from posting.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it's gone beyond the point where the community should be responsible, in my opinion. It's a bigger problem than that.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 in which case, you'd have to ban PHP and regex tags as well

Comment: @JanDvorak Look at a sample of 100 current questions. How many are basic jQuery questions that could be answered using google / a book? I'm also not advocating banning anything. It was mearly a question.

Answer (score 9):

jQuery questions aren't ruining Stack Overflow. They aren't. Perhaps they are ruining your Stack Overflow experience because that's a tag where you are primarily active. And your narrow view of the site might lead you to think the site is an absolute garbage pile. But I'm (mostly) happily oblivious of jQuery, and don't at all share your view. Sure, improvements can be made, and there certainly is a thing or two that annoys me every now and then, but what do you expect on a site this large?

So let's for a moment assume the situation in the jQuery tag is as bad as you say it is. Heck, substitute jQuery for any of the other tags that regularly complains about how bad the content is, the situation doesn't change.

Banning the tag is not the answer. jQuery is legitimately on-topic for the site. And mods don't need to be involved either. What are they going to do? Your dirty work? With all the subsequent flak of "moderator abuse" and "s/he's not even active in these tags"?. Nah.

Each concerned member has an X number of close votes each day, as well as an X number of downvotes. If you are all concerned about this specific tag, filter your review queues to focus on that tag. Downvote all bad content. Both questions (which you can downvote for free) and answers to questions which really shouldn't be answered or are equally horrendous. Be active in your tag-specific chat room. Help each other out.

If you do that, and do that consistently as a community, I'm certain you can make a big dent in the mess you've identified. Once you have exhausted all your means (and I would be surprised if you have already) then you can call upon those behind the scenes (be it moderators or CMs) to see if something additional is required. But for now I would assume the answer is simply, assemble and get to work.

Comment: everything you say is right. But honestly, I don't think it'll ever work. Again, it's the *volume* that's the issue. But as I said, I don't disagree with what you're saying and thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: It won't work if you won't even try. ;)

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9: The volume is a fact of life. I genuinely believe we can trace a majority of _humanity_'s problems to overcrowding and scale, not just SO's. There's nothing we can do about it. What is your question about? Is it just a rant? Are you just making us aware of the problem? Oh, don't worry, we are _all_ very much aware.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 - In addition to what Bart said, there is a precedent for the community coming together to clean up a particular tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100529/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag . I think we've seen positive improvements in [android] as a result. Also, you can see that there are a lot worse tags than [jquery], in terms of the metrics we can measure.

Comment: My pet peeve is pure-JS questions where the top accepted answer uses jQuery.  I'd like to see at least those answers receive a pure-JS howto as well.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery...ruining SO?  LOL...in the words of a great philosopher..." 'Twas ever thus."

Comment: Did you actually laugh at loud. Really?

Comment: @Liverpool, that's "out", as in [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah I see. Sorry. Not a teenager.